# ¿Cómo modificar valor de localstorage con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo un DIV que es para dar *likes* y este al darle clic cambia de clase la cual modifica el color. Lo que quiero es que cada vez que se dé clic cambie de clase y se guarde un valor que sea entre "true" o "false". He visto una pregunta similar pero es con objeto, lo cual no me ayudó mucho.

Esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```js
let heart = document.getElementById("heart");
console.log( localStorage.getItem("liked"));

if(localStorage.getItem("liked") == "true"){
    heart.classList.add("heartClick");
}else{
    dioLike();
}

function dioLike(){
  heart.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem("liked")){
        localStorage.setItem("liked", "true");
        localStorage.getItem("liked");
        heart.classList.add("heartClick");
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem("liked", "false");
       localStorage.getItem("liked");
       heart.classList.remove("heartClick");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Feliz Navidad</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="dioLike()">
        <div class="heart" id="heart"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas que cambie el localStorage al hacer click al div, puedes hacer uso de la función onClick, teniendo lo siguiente en el html:

```
<body>
<div class="heart" id="heart" onclick="dioLike()"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

y en el script se puede establecer una función con window.onload que verifique si en el localStorage existe el item "liked" guardado con "true" y agregue la clase, quedando el script de la siguiente manera:

```
let heart = document.getElementById("heart");

window.onload = function(){
if(localStorage.getItem("liked")==="true"){
    heart.classList.add("heartClick");
}else{
  return;
}
}

function dioLike(){
if(localStorage.getItem("liked")==="false"){
    localStorage.setItem("liked", "true");
    heart.classList.add("heartClick");

}else{
    localStorage.setItem("liked", "false");
    heart.classList.remove("heartClick");
}
};
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, me funciono, pero no deberia de funcionar igual el onClick como el addEventListener("click") ?

Comment: Funciona de igual manera, pero en el codigo dado, el addEventListener debe estar fuera de la función dioLike, de manera que se le pase como parámetro: heart.addEventListener("click", dioLike); Espero te sirva

Comment: Si bien es ampliamente usado, [se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos _inline_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) (como `onclick`).

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene al menos 2 problemas:

1. La función `dioLike()` se ejecuta 2 veces al inicio, lo que ocasiona que agregas 2 eventos `click` al div, y como tienes una funcionalidad binaria, al ejecutarse 2 veces siempre quedará donde mismo
2. Lo que guardas son `string`  **NO** booleanos, por lo que todas tus evaluaciones no funcionan con tu esperas.

Por ejemplo, estas haciendo esto:

```js
if("false"){
   console.log("Según tu, No deberia entrar aquí, pero como ves si lo hace");
}
```

El ejemplo anterior es lo que te pasa en

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("liked")){
  //Aquí solo entrará una vez en la vida, y es cuando
  //'localStorage.getItem("liked")' sea nulo, luego no entrará más

} else {
  //Aquí entrará todas las otras veces, porque cualquier string se
  //evalúa como verdadero y negado siempre será falso
}
```

Entonces lo que hay que hacer es, que no se ejecuta 2 veces `dioLike()` y luego convertir el string "true" en un booleano `true`, usando esto

```
const valor = liked == "true";
```

Entonces debes hacer algo como esto:

```js
function Init(){
    SetLike(GetLike()); //inicializamos con el valor guardado
    heart.addEventListener("click", () => SetLike(!GetLike())); //cambiamos el valor en cada click, notar el operador negación -> "!" 
}    
function GetLike() {
    const liked = localStorage.getItem("liked") || "false"; //false será el valor por defecto, cuando no exista nada guardado
    return liked == "true";
}
function SetLike(valor) {
    localStorage.setItem("liked", valor);
    heart.classList.toggle("heartClick",valor);
}
```

```html
<body onload="Init()">
    <div class="heart" id="heart"></div>
</body>
```